# Make all keys in s3 bucket private

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with 10^6 keys in it. I want to make all objects in it private.

I tried s3cmd which fails after sometime. 
I tried it with boto3, but it is painfully slow.

```
import boto3

boto3.setup_default_session(aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket_acl = bucket.Acl()

i = 0

for object_summary in bucket.objects.all():
    i += 1
    object_acl = object_summary.Acl()
    if i % 100 == 1:
        print('{} {}'.format(i, object_summary.key))

    object_acl.put(ACL='private')
```

Is there any way to do batch operation or do everything private by setting some bucket policy.

Any other suggestion is also welcome.

Comment: What makes you think that your objects are not private already? Were they uploaded with a Public ACL setting?

Comment: How did these objects all become public to begin with?

Comment: They are currently in public state. Our dev created each object public (by public ACL), but with a complex url to secure them. We are now generating presigned url as needed. But we still need to make the old urls private.       I had run the python code in nohup mode. It has reached 30K objects in 2-3 hours so far.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i did not find a good solution. I decided to run it for 70 hours with nohup in background.

A possible solution I thought was to split keys in bucket into multiple sets and run them using multiple threads.

But in the end I just waited 70 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**.

Things that make them public are:

- Bucket Polices on the bucket containing the objects
- Permissions granted to Users, Groups and Roles in Amazon IAM
- Permissions applied specifically to each object ("ACLs")